# The GET method is not supported for this route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project and I have built this form for verifying token:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <form action="{{ route('profile.2fa.phone') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="token" class="col-form-label">Token</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control @error('token') is-invalid @enderror" name="token" placeholder="enter your token">
            @error('token')
                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Validate token</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And then at `web.php` I have these routes:

```
Route::get('/settings/twofactor/phone' , [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'getPhoneVerify']);

Route::post('/settings/twofactor/phone' , [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'postPhoneVerify'])->name('profile.2fa.phone');
```

But now when I add the token and press the *Validate Token* button, I get this error:

> **Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException**
> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST.

So what is going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing `<button ` to `<input type="submit" `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to check if your routes are being property created.
Execute: `php artisan route:list`.
If there is nothing about `POST`, execute this commands:

```sh
    php artisan config:cache // clear config cache
    php artisan config:clear // clear config cache
    php artisan cache:clear // clear cache
    php artisan optimize  // To reoptimize the class loader
    php artisan route:cache // clear route cache
    php artisan view:clear // clear view cache
```

In a easy way - `php artisan optimize`.

If that's did not help make sure that your route is route, that you are searching for.

UDP: `name` method is not working as you want. Try to declare name with out this method.

If you want, you can try to use this format of routes:
`Route::match(['get', 'post'], ...);`

Comment: I test that, but the error still occurs: `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

Comment: Can you write an example of using `Route::match`

Comment: yeah, here it is: `Route::match([<supported methods>], <route>, [Someclass::class, 'some_method_of_this_class'])->methods();`

Comment: For your situation: 
`Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/settings/twofactor/phone', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'postPhoneVerify', 'getPhoneVerify']);`

Comment: Then shoud I add `->name('profile.2fa.phone')` at the end of it or just add `/settings/twofactor/phone` uri as form action ?

Comment: i gues you should try both of this variants

Comment: `Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/settings/twofactor/phone', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'postPhoneVerify', 'getPhoneVerify'])->name('profile.2fa.phone');` Solved it

Comment: Glad that helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

Laravel will match routes in the order they are declared.

To fix your problem you need to declare your `Route::post` before `Route::get`.

Your GET request should always be declared as the last method in your route list as it will trap any other request with a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.